# How to publish for both private and work customers?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I've an app that has been published for Google for Work customers (on the Google Apps Marketplace), private customers and for Google Drive users.
So in my manifest I have specified the container like this:

```
  "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE", "GOOGLE_DRIVE"]
```

While the app shows up when installing from Google Drive (Add more apps...) or from the Google Apps dashboard, it does not show up in the CWS in its main category or when selecting "Works with Google Drive".

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are also publishing your app as a Chrome Web Store packaged or hosted app for consumers, you'll need to create a separate listing for that: you cannot simply add the app information to this manifest. See [Publishing Your App](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish) in the Chrome Web Store documentation for details.

Check this [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) for more details.

Hope that helps!